# Can I know the ratio of the impact between two events on their combined outcome?

Tags: statistics, analytics, correlation

I have a table of outcomes that depend on existence/absence of the event A and event B

```js
const data = [
   { a: 0, b: 0, v: 256000 },
   { a: 1, b: 0, v: 96000 },
   { a: 0, b: 1, v: 220160 },
   { a: 1, b: 1, v: 82560 },
]
```

I see that when both event A and event B happened, the outcome value is 82,560, much lower than the outcome when neither A nor B happened - 256,000.

And I have a question, given this table, can I estimate how much A influenced the lowering of the outcome compared to event B?

I mean, in the result, I want to get some numbers X and Y. Which I can use in the sentence: "X% of the failure were due the event A and Y% of the failure were due the event B."

If I cannot estimate it - which data do I need additionally to estimate it?

I've calculated two "correlations":

- correlation between `a` and `v`
- correlation between `b` and `v`

I've got such numbers:

```js
{
    cav: -0.9838565509452193,
    cbv: -0.16291818155436963
}
```

And I calculated how much `cav` is compared to `cav + cbv` and the same for `cbv`.

I've got these numbers:

```js
a: 86%,
b: 14%,
```

But I am not sure if it has any sense at all. Since I am not a statistician.